# How to get the circus troupe merchant to show up?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-hearts-of-stone

I'm trying to round out my early game Gwent deck. According to multiple sources, there should be a [Circus troupe encampment](https://witcher.gamepedia.com/Circus_troupe_encampment) northwest of Carsten, west of the Vegelbud estate. There I want to find [this merchant who sells multiple cards](https://witcher.gamepedia.com/Merchant_(circus_troupe)). However, when I go there the area is completely empty.

Does the camp only appear later in the game, or during a particular quest? Or is there some other condition to unlocking him?

I have the Steam GOTY edition with all DLCs installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting the "Open Sesame! Breaking and Entering" quest (part of Hearts of Stone) will make the troupe appear. I'm not sure if there are any other ways to get it.

Comment: Thanks! The quest is part of the Hearts of Stone Expansion, am I correct that I can only start the questline around level 30? I'm level 17 right now, according to the Wiki the questline starts at the Seven Cats Inn, but I haven't gotten the quest there yet ...

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a minimum level to get the initial 'Evil's First Soft Touches" quest. Looking at the notice board at the Seven Cats is the way it starts.

Comment: Thanks! My bad, I just realized I haven't actually gotten the expansion yet ... thought it was included in the GOTY edition. I bought it now, I'm sure it will work then.

Comment: Hope you enjoy it! The story there was terrific IMO. Same with Blood and Wine, which is even larger (larger than Witcher 2!).